# MAUI Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.'

Tags: android, .net, xaml, maui

So i have collection view with item template selector. Both this templates also have own collection view with item template selector. When i adding first element to inner collection view, everything is ok. But when i tried to add second element i got exception. The problem, as I understand it, is not in this nesting, because I reworked my example to have only one collection with the item template selector, but I still got the same error.

Error stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5248)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5077)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5017)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4989)
    at crc645d80431ce5f73f11.GroupableItemsViewAdapter_2.n_onBindViewHolder(Native Method)
    at crc645d80431ce5f73f11.GroupableItemsViewAdapter_2.onBindViewHolder(GroupableItemsViewAdapter_2.java:48)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:2028)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewFlinger.run(RecyclerView.java:5434)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:827)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

My view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Views.TestEditorView"             
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Behaviors"
             xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.CustomControls"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Models"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:selectors="clr-namespace:Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Selectors"               
             x:DataType="viewModel:TestEditorViewModel"
             x:Name="TestEditorPage"
             Title="TestEditorView">   

    <ContentPage.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:IntToBoolConverter x:Key="IntToBoolConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>           

       

        <Style x:Key="TestEditor"
               TargetType="Editor">

            <Style.Setters>

                <Setter Property="AutoSize" Value="TextChanges"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1"/>
                <Setter Property="Placeholder" Value="Enter question answer"/>
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type models:TestAnswerResponse}}, Path=Answer}"/>

                <Setter Property="behaviors:TestEditorStyleBehavior.AttachBehavior">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Unfocused"
                                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.UnfocusedCommand}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                
            </Style.Setters>
            
        </Style> 

        //Other data templates


        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultQuestion" x:DataType="models:TestQuestion">
            <Border StrokeThickness="3.5">

                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10"></RoundRectangle>
                </Border.StrokeShape>

                <StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout>

                        <Grid Padding="15" ColumnSpacing="15">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding QuestionNumber, StringFormat='Question {0}'}"/>

                            <customControls:ImageControl Grid.Column="1" 
                                                                 Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteTestQuestionCommand}" 
                                                                 CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                                 ImageSource="dotnet_bot.svg"/>


                            <customControls:ImageControl Grid.Column="2" 
                                                                 Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteTestQuestionCommand}" 
                                                                 CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                                                                 ImageSource="dotnet_bot.svg"/>

                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>

                    <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HeightRequest="3.5" Color="LightGray"/>

                    <StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Spacing="10" Margin="10,20">

                            <Editor Text="{Binding Question}" Style="{StaticResource TestEditor}" Grid.Column="0"/>                     

                        </StackLayout>

                        <BoxView Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HeightRequest="3" Color="LightGray"/>

                        <StackLayout Padding="20,5">

                            <toolkit:Expander  IsExpanded="True">
                                <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                    <Border StrokeThickness="3.5" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10"/>
                                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Question answers" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="dotnet_bot.svg" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </toolkit:Expander.Header>

                                <CollectionView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestAnswerTemplate}"                                                                                                
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding TestAnswers}"                                                
                                                ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
                                                EmptyView="Here is no questions currently. Push the button below to add new question"/>
                            </toolkit:Expander>

                            //Exception when i press this button second time
                            <Button Text="Add test answer"
                                            Margin="5,10"
                                            Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.AddTestAnswerCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

                        </StackLayout>

                        <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HeightRequest="3" Color="LightGray"/>

                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Margin="20,10,20,10" Spacing="15">

                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Points per one answer: "/>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"  Padding="5" Grid.Column="1">
                                <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="5">
                                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference stepper}, Path=Value}"/>
                                    <Stepper x:Name="stepper" Minimum="0.25" Maximum="5" Increment="0.25" Value="{Binding PointsPerAnswer}" WidthRequest="100"/>
                                </HorizontalStackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>

                    </StackLayout>

                </StackLayout>

            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionWithSpaces" x:DataType="models:TestQuestion">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource defaultBorder}">
                <StackLayout>
                    <customControls:TestElementHeaderControl Header="{Binding QuestionNumber, StringFormat='Question {0}'}">

                        <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="5">

                            <ImageButton Source="dotnet_bot.svg"                                     
                                         WidthRequest="30"
                                         HeightRequest="30"                               
                                         Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestEditorPage}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteTestQuestionCommand}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>                           

                        </HorizontalStackLayout>

                    </customControls:TestElementHeaderControl>
                    
                    <BoxView Style="{StaticResource defaultBoxView}"/>                    
                   
                    <StackLayout Padding="15">      
                      

                            <toolkit:Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                    <Border StrokeThickness="3.5" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                                        <Border.StrokeShape>
                                            <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="10"/>
                                        </Border.StrokeShape>
                                        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto">
                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Question spaces" FontSize="15"/>
                                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="dotnet_bot.svg" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </toolkit:Expander.Header>

                                <CollectionView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestAnswerTemplate}"                                                                                                
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding TestAnswers}"                                                
                                                ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
                                                EmptyView="Here is no questions currently. Push the button below to add new space">            

                            </toolkit:Expander>                         

                        </StackLayout>
                        
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <selectors:TestQuestionDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TestQuestionTemplate"
                                                    DefaultQuestion="{x:StaticResource DefaultQuestion}"
                                                    SpacesQuestion="{x:StaticResource QuestionWithSpaces}"/>

        <selectors:TestAnswerDataTemplateSelector x:Key="TestAnswerTemplate" 
                                                  OneAnswerQuestion="{x:StaticResource OneAnswerQuestion}"
                                                  MultipleAnswerQuestion="{x:StaticResource MultipleAnswerQuestion}"
                                                  PairsQuestion="{x:StaticResource PairsQuestion}"
                                                  OpenEndedQuestion="{x:StaticResource OpenEndedQuestion}"
                                                  SpacesQuestion="{x:StaticResource SpacesQuestion}"/>

    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <StackLayout>       
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*, Auto" ColumnSpacing="10" Margin="10,10">

            <customControls:DropDownButton ItemSource="{Binding TestQuestionTypesValues}"
                                           IsDisplayPickerControl="{Binding IsDisplayPicker}"                                    
                                           CurrentItem="{Binding SelectedQuestionTypeValue}"
                                           OpenPickerCommand="{Binding OpenPickerCommand}"
                                           PickerHeightRequest="300"
                                           Grid.Column="0"                                            
                                           DisplayedMember="TypeValue">

                <customControls:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:TestQuestionTypeValues">
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Style="{x:StaticResource stackLayoutSelectionStyle}" Margin="15">
                            <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding TypeValue}" FontSize="Large"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </customControls:DropDownButton.ItemTemplate>

            </customControls:DropDownButton>

            <Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddTestQuestionCommand}" Grid.Column="1"/>

        </Grid>        

        <CollectionView ItemsSource ="{Binding Test.TestQuestions}"                          
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"                    
                        SelectionMode="None"  
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TestQuestionTemplate}"
                        ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
                        x:Name="TestsCollectionView">          
            
        </CollectionView>         
        
    </StackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

Also view model code:

```
using Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Models;
using Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.Services;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Syncfusion.Maui.DataSource.Extensions;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Bibliomatic_MAUI_App.ViewModels
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(Test), "Test")]
    public partial class TestEditorViewModel : ObservableObject
    {        
        public List<TestQuestionType> TestQuestionTypes { get; set; } = new List<TestQuestionType>();
        public ObservableCollection<TestQuestionTypeValues> TestQuestionTypesValues { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TestQuestionTypeValues>();  

        [ObservableProperty]
        public TestResponse test;      

        [ObservableProperty]
        public TestQuestionTypeValues selectedQuestionTypeValue;      

        private readonly LocalTestKeeper localTestKeeper;
        private readonly LocalTestQuestionImagesKeeper localTestQuestionImagesKeeper;
        private readonly LocalTestAnswerImagesKeeper localTestAnswerImagesKeeper;

        public TestEditorViewModel(LocalTestKeeper localTestKeeper,
                                   LocalTestQuestionImagesKeeper localTestQuestionImagesKeeper,
                                   LocalTestAnswerImagesKeeper localTestAnswerImagesKeeper)
        {            
            this.localTestKeeper = localTestKeeper;
            this.localTestQuestionImagesKeeper = localTestQuestionImagesKeeper;
            this.localTestAnswerImagesKeeper = localTestAnswerImagesKeeper;            
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void OpenPicker()
        {
            TestQuestionTypesValues.Clear();

            List<TestQuestionType> testQuestionTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestQuestionType))
                                                           .Cast<TestQuestionType>()
                                                           .ToList();            

            testQuestionTypes.ForEach(qt => TestQuestionTypesValues.Add(new TestQuestionTypeValues(qt)));       
        }
        

        [RelayCommand] 
        public void AddTestQuestion()
        {        
            var questionToBeAdded = new TestQuestion
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Question = string.Empty,
                Test = Test,
                TestId = Test.Id,
                IsUpdated = false,
                QuestionNumber = Test.TestQuestions.Count + 1,
                TestQuestionType = SelectedQuestionTypeValue.Type,
                QuestionImageSource = string.Empty,
                TestAnswers = new ObservableCollection<TestAnswerResponse>(),
                DeletedTestAnswers = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, TestAnswer>>()
            };
                     
            Test.TestQuestions.Add(questionToBeAdded);
        }       
       

        [RelayCommand]
        public void DeleteTestQuestion(TestQuestion selectedTestQuestion)
        {
            Test.TestQuestions.Remove(selectedTestQuestion);

            Test.TestQuestions.Cast<TestQuestion>()
                              .Where(tq => tq.QuestionNumber > selectedTestQuestion.QuestionNumber)
                              .ForEach(tq => tq.QuestionNumber--);
                                                          
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void AddTestAnswer(TestQuestion selectedTestQuestion)
        {
            var answerToBeAdded = new TestAnswer
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Answer = string.Empty,
                Variant = string.Empty,
                Message = string.Empty,
                IsSelected = false,
                AnswerNumber = selectedTestQuestion.TestAnswers.Count + 1,
                SelectedTestAnswer = null,
                TestQuestion = selectedTestQuestion,
                TestQuestionId = selectedTestQuestion.Id,
                IsCorrectAnswer = false
            };

            selectedTestQuestion.TestAnswers.Add(answerToBeAdded);          
        }       

        [RelayCommand]
        public void DeleteTestAnswer(TestAnswer selectedTestAnswer)
        {
            var selectedTestQuestion = selectedTestAnswer.TestQuestion;
            selectedTestQuestion.TestAnswers.Remove(selectedTestAnswer);
            
            UpdateAnswerNumberWhenRemove(selectedTestQuestion, selectedTestAnswer);            
        }

        public void UpdateAnswerNumberWhenRemove(TestQuestionResponse testQuestion, TestAnswer testAnswer)
        {
            testQuestion.TestAnswers.Cast<TestAnswer>()
                                    .Where(ta => ta.AnswerNumber > testAnswer.AnswerNumber)
                                    .ForEach(ta => ta.AnswerNumber--);
        }

        public void UpdateAnswerNumberWhenInsert(TestQuestion testQuestion)
        {            
            for (int index = 0; index < testQuestion.TestAnswers.Count; index++)            
                ((TestAnswer)testQuestion.TestAnswers.ElementAt(index)).AnswerNumber = index + 1;                      
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void PickTestQuestionImage(TestQuestion selectedTestQuestion)
        {
            var image = await PickImage();

            if (image == null)
                return;

            var imagePath = await localTestQuestionImagesKeeper.SaveFileToLocalStorage(selectedTestQuestion, image);
            selectedTestQuestion.QuestionImageSource = imagePath;                 
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void PickTestAnswerImage(TestAnswer selectedTestAnswer)
        {
            var image = await PickImage();

            if (image == null)
                return;

            string oldAnswerImagePath = selectedTestAnswer.AnswerImageSource;
            string newAnswerImagePath = await localTestAnswerImagesKeeper.SaveFileToLocalStorage(selectedTestAnswer, image, oldAnswerImagePath);

            selectedTestAnswer.AnswerImageSource = newAnswerImagePath;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void PickTestVariantImage(TestAnswer selectedTestAnswer)
        {
            var image = await PickImage();

            if(image == null)
                return;

            string oldVariantImagePath = selectedTestAnswer.VariantImageSource;
            string newVariantImagePath = await localTestAnswerImagesKeeper.SaveFileToLocalStorage(selectedTestAnswer, image, oldVariantImagePath);

            selectedTestAnswer.VariantImageSource = newVariantImagePath;
        }

        private async Task<FileResult> PickImage()
        {
            var selectedImage = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Please select image"
            });

            return selectedImage;
        }     

        [RelayCommand]
        public async void Unfocused()
        {            
            await localTestKeeper.SaveFileToLocalStorage(Test);                
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code and xaml. I recommend making a new project, and reducing the code/xaml to the minimum that shows the error. If its not the nesting, then don't nest in your test. Once you've found the minimum, see if you can get error to go away by removing even more. Ideally, you'll have two sets of code/xaml: one that works, and a slightly different one that fails. That would be best starting point for either helping you, or determining that it is a maui bug.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I’ll will follow your advise, thanks